# How can I remove certain edges?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I remove certain vertical edges, as seen here in the image?

[image]

Comment: Just a tip: I don't know what your native language is, but I notice that your questions are usually written in a relatively difficult to understand way. I can recommend this translator: https://www.deepl.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

[image]

I just compare whether x and y coordinates of each edge vertex are the same, if yes -> delete that edge.

Comment: Works, Thank You !!!

Comment: You are welcome!!!

Answer (score 1):

Chris's answer is flawless, and it works beautifully.

However, if you want to select the edges based on a direction vector (and maybe even define a certain tolerance value), then this solution might be almost a little better. ...at least you even save a whole node ;-)

[image]

*PS: With Epsilon you define the tolerance, and with the vector $B$ the direction.*

---

You can also use this technique to filter any other edge. For example, you can select all vertical edges.

Or you can simply reverse the selection with the `Boolean Math` node, which will also remove all non-vertical edges:

[image]

Comment: Thank You, great solution !!!