# how to remove vertical lines ? you need to leave only the vertical

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, lines

[image]

how to remove vertical lines . you need to leave only the vertical. geometry nodes

[image]

[image]

Comment: This answers the question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264307/ You can simply invert the selection here with the node `Boolean Math` (set to *Not*). Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C01ML.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot product is useful here.

[image]

Dot product is used to get information about how mach one vector is aligned to the other.

Note that order of vertex may differ, so I've used two compare nodes, for up and down directions.

Comment: I tried to do as you said. It didn't work out (

Comment: attached screenshots from above

Comment: you haven't connected second compare node

Comment: quick improvement: you can skip the normalize if the compare node is set to *direction*. you could also just use one compare node if you take the *absolute* vector [with the absolute operation in the *vector math* node]. then you get rid of two nodes.